# npm start permission denied but node command working

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

In package.json i have npm start command like:

```
"start": "node app/src/Server.js",
```

when i am using "npm start" command then it thrown error of permission denied to open .pem file (ssl file)

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname/privkey.pem'
```

But if i use direct command node app/src/Server.js then it is working.
How i can resolve permission issue with npm start?
I am using root user only.